# How to implement editable field for an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, inline-editing, best-in-place

I need to find a way my tasks could be edited in such a manner without updating a page. Maybe somebody know how to do it? I know it applies to Angularjs. But I really haven't found any information for my purpose.

When you click on some task, you can edit its content.
[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: You dont need angular.js for in place editing, you can look at https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place and http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Comment: @AmitBadhekaPykihStaff Thanks man.

Comment: https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place is the gem that i use when I have to do think kind of thing is really simple and it has a great tutorial on rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [gem 'best_in_place'](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) you can follow implementing it from the [In-Place Editing rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing)

what you have to do is in 
**app/assets/javascripts/application.js** add the following files

```
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
```

**app/assets/javascripts/model_name.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

lastly on **model/show.html.erb**

```
<p>
  <b>Field Name:</b>
  <%= best_in_place @model, :field_name %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <%= best_in_place @model, :email %>
</p>
```

That should be all you kneed. 
Happy coding